# Get pairs of point coordinates for Daubechies wavelets generated with scipy.daub in Python

Tags: javascript, python, matplotlib, scipy, signal-processing

I've been trying to get the coordinates of the points that make up a Daubechies wavelet generated with scipy.daub, in order to send them across a websocket and have them plotted on a Canvas.js dynamic chart.

I managed to send the data over to the browser and have the points plotted on the chart (so there's no issue there), but all I get is sawtooth waveforms. I realised this is due to the fact that for each Y coordinate I receive, I increase the x value by 1.

However, perfect Daubechies wavelets are plotted using matplotlib.pylab and the returned list of points contains the y values, as far as I can tell. Here's how I generate the wavelets (it's meant to become an ECG simulator btw):

```
def generate_waves(hr, n):
    global ecg
    interval = 1.0 * 60 / hr
    rr = [interval + random.uniform(0.0, 0.1 * interval) for i in range(n)]
    fs = 1000.0  # sampling rate
    pqrst = scipy.signal.daub(9)
    ecg = scipy.concatenate([scipy.signal.resample(pqrst, int(r*fs)) for r in rr])
    t = scipy.arange(len(ecg))/fs
    pylab.plot(t, ecg)
    pylab.show()
```

So, since the ecg list returns the y values, is there any way I can get hold of the x values so I can pass them through the websocket together and properly plot them on the chart?

Cheers!

Comment: Increasing the x value by 1 seems to be fine, since your samples appear to be equally spaced. The fact that you get a sawtooth waveform sounds more like there is something wrong with the y values.

Comment: That's what I was trying to explain up there, the same y values input into pylab.plot produce the desired waveform. So I don't see how they could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured it out. The x values are given by t. Pretty stupid of me not to have seen this, I know.

Thanks anyway!